# Java use in Anylogic - How to convert variable string to type 'TargetLine'

Tags: java, anylogic

Using Java in Anylogic I have a variable set to type other 'TargetLine'. I then use that variable within pedestrian moveTo blocks to dynamically change the location TargetLine.

I wish to assign another string value variable to this TargetLine variable, how do I first convert to type 'TargetLine' please?

Any advice gratefully received.

ie:

```
var_TargetLine = var_MyString
```

Comment: I think it is bad practice to change the type for variables in general. Avoid this. Why would you want to change a TargetLine variable to a String?

Comment: Its the other way around. I wish to keep the type TargetLine but I have another variable of type String which I need to assign to TargetLine.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a variable of type String to a variable of type TargetLine"? Do you mean your string is also the name of a TargetLine somewhere in your model and you want to now replace the TargetLine in yoiur TargetLine-type variable with that?

Comment: Yes exactly that. My string is the name of a TargetLine somewhere. The moveTo block uses that TargetLine variable, which I want to update with a different value.

Comment: I see. Then, you should not use a String here but a TargetLine object directly. See my reply below for how to get a TargetLine by name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a TargetLine by name, first you must have all possible TargetLine objects in a collection of type ArrayList (call it col_MyLines). You can do that at design time manually or at runtime using `col_MyLines.add(myTargetLine)`

Now, you create a function f_getTargetLineByName with input argument "name" of type String that returns a TargetLine. Fill it with this code:

```
for (TargetLine currentLine : col_MyLines) {
    if (currentLine.getName().equals(name) {
        return currentLine;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Benjamin! Qudos, thank you, this maybe exactly what I'm looking for. Will report back if it works. I was currently using the following:

Comment: var_A = tl_1;

var_B = findFirst(ground.getTargetLines(), n->n.getName().equals("tl_1"));

Comment: This might be even more efficient :-) just replace "tl_1" with "var_A", no?

Comment: But note, I was getting an odd problem what the value (targetLine) I was searching already existed in another variable.

Comment: Assigning var_A with the same value was to prove the issue